# Iterating over JSON objects with HAML Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am relatively new to ruby on rails and haml. I want to get the name from my JSON object in haml.

I have this in my .rb file

```
campaigns = '[{"name":"Campaign_1"},{"name":"Campaign_2"},{"name":"Campaign_3"}]'
render "evaluate" , :locals => {:campaigns => campaigns}
```

I want to print out "Campaign_1", "Campaign_2" ... from the name. This is what I have in my haml file. I have tried several variations of this for loop but none have quite worked. This is my latest one.

This is what I have in my haml file:

```
- for campaign in @campaigns
        %input{:type => "checkbox"}
          - campaign.name
```

This gives me

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

**Important Note:**
This haml file is a partial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use locals to pass values to your views.  In your controller code, you need to convert from JSON to a hash and fix locals syntax:

```
json_campaigns = '[{"name":"Campaign_1"},{"name":"Campaign_2"},{"name":"Campaign_3"}]'
campaigns = JSON.parse json_campaigns
render "evaluate" , :locals => {campaigns: campaigns}
```

In your view:

```
- campaigns.each do |c|
  %input{:type => "checkbox"}
    = c["name"]
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to do this in a partial which was giving me these errors. How would I do this in a partial?

Comment: how do you do that? :partials => {campaigns: campaigns}? This gives me a very weird error

Comment: You can pass locals to a partial as well, but the local variable won't have the @ (campaigns, not @campaigns).  Also, I'm not sure you want to render a partial from a controller.  Just render your view and you can always factor code from the view into a partial if necessary to DRY it up.

Comment: Oh..... I get it so I have to edit my evaluate template and there pass again the local variables that were already passed to it by the controller. I assumed inherited variables but I understand now that was a flawed assumption. This worked!!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`@campaign` is not defined because you created a local variable in your controller, not an instance variable.
You need to add `@campaigns` in your controller to be able to access it in your views.

Edit:

Controller:

```
@campaigns = '[{"name":"Campaign_1"},{"name":"Campaign_2"}.{"name":"Campaign_3"}]'
render "evaluate" , :locals => {:campaigns => campaigns}`
```

View:

```
- for campaign in @campaigns
    %input{:type => "checkbox"}
      - campaign.name
```

Comment: The rb file that code is from is in the controller so I am not sure what you mean. What would I need to change in order to get the name from every object in the JSON string?

Comment: the for loop is in your controller? @user1917363

Comment: No. The for loop is in the haml file

Comment: Okay so follow what the answer says...
In your controller you created a `local variable` that is only apart of the controller.  You need to create an `instance variable` so your view can see it.

Comment: I get the error undefined local variable or method `campaigns' for #<AdwordsCampaignPerformanceController:0x0000000861ecb8>

Comment: I changed the render line so it sends :campaigns => @campaigns and that gives me "undefined method `each' for #<String:0x0000000906a118>"